# How to get token id from Stripe function using ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, strip

I want to  implement the payment gateway using the stripe in ionic 3 
I got the response from the stripe but I want to store that token.
How to access it ?

```
    this.stripe.createCardToken(this.card)
    .then(token => console.log(token))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

[response from strip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3xs5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The `token` you get back, and are logging **is** the token.  That is what you need to store and use in your server to make a charge.